# Google Maps Api - drawing routes from an array of points

Tags: google-maps

I would like to connect 8 points on google map so that they shared line (road). I would like to click on the point cloud showed up with a description that point. The goal is to show the route the car point to point.

I have script to make map with points but I don't know how connect markers.

```
var MapPoints = '[{"address":{"address":"plac Grzybowski, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2360592","lng":"21.002903599999968"},"title":"Warszawa"},{"address":{"address":"Jana Paw\u0142a II, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2179967","lng":"21.222655600000053"},"title":"Wroc\u0142aw"},{"address":{"address":"Wawelska, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2166692","lng":"20.993677599999955"},"title":"O\u015bwi\u0119cim"}]';

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';
function initialize() {

if (jQuery('#map').length > 0) {

    var locations = jQuery.parseJSON(MapPoints);

    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].address.lat, locations[i].address.lng),
            map: map
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['title']);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    var flightPath = responseArray.map(function (item) {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
    });

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
        map.setZoom(12);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
 }
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- to connect your markers with a google.maps.Polyline (as it looks like you are trying to do).

  1. create an empty array: `var flightPlanCoordinates = [];`
  2. push the coordinates of the markers (google.maps.LatLng objects) into the  array of coordinates you use for the polyline: `flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());`
  3. set the `map` option of the polyline: `map:map` (in the PolylineOptions object).

     ```
     var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         map: map,
         path: flightPlanCoordinates,
         strokeColor: "#FF0000",
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
     });
     ```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcjg5jxL/)

**working code snippet:**

```js
var MapPoints = '[{"address":{"address":"plac Grzybowski, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2360592","lng":"21.002903599999968"},"title":"Warszawa"},{"address":{"address":"Jana Paw\u0142a II, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2179967","lng":"21.222655600000053"},"title":"Wroc\u0142aw"},{"address":{"address":"Wawelska, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2166692","lng":"20.993677599999955"},"title":"O\u015bwi\u0119cim"}]';

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

  if (jQuery('#map').length > 0) {

    var locations = jQuery.parseJSON(MapPoints);

    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].address.lat, locations[i].address.lng),
        map: map
      });
      flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());
      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['title']);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

- to connect the points using the directions service (from [the example you reference](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints))

  1. create an empty array: `var flightPlanCoordinates = [];`
  2. push the coordinates of the markers (google.maps.LatLng objects) into the  array of coordinates you use for the polyline: `flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());`
  3. use that array to populate the `start`, `end`, and `waypts` arguments into the calcRoute function:

     ```
     var start = flightPlanCoordinates[0];
     var end = flightPlanCoordinates[flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1];
     var waypts = [];
     for (var i = 1; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
         waypts.push({
             location: flightPlanCoordinates[i],
             stopover: true
         });
     }
     calcRoute(start, end, waypts);
     ```
  4. change the `calcRoute` function to use those arguments:

     ```
     function calcRoute(start, end, waypts) {
         var request = {
         origin: start,
         destination: end,
         waypoints: waypts,
         optimizeWaypoints: true,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
     };
     ```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ave5fzp9/)

**working code snippet:**

```js
var MapPoints = '[{"address":{"address":"plac Grzybowski, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2360592","lng":"21.002903599999968"},"title":"Warszawa"},{"address":{"address":"Jana Paw\u0142a II, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2179967","lng":"21.222655600000053"},"title":"Wroc\u0142aw"},{"address":{"address":"Wawelska, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2166692","lng":"20.993677599999955"},"title":"O\u015bwi\u0119cim"}]';

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });

  if (jQuery('#map').length > 0) {

    var locations = jQuery.parseJSON(MapPoints);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].address.lat, locations[i].address.lng),
        map: map
      });
      flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());
      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['title']);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // directions service configuration
    var start = flightPlanCoordinates[0];
    var end = flightPlanCoordinates[flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1];
    var waypts = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
      waypts.push({
        location: flightPlanCoordinates[i],
        stopover: true
      });
    }
    calcRoute(start, end, waypts);
  }
}

function calcRoute(start, end, waypts) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="directions_panel"></div>
```