# How to draw known route using Google Map JavsScript API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on like-taxi web application, where I need to draw routes from driving history, but I can't understand how to do this. For example, I have a previously known route and I need to show it to user, not to draw a new using standard API function. 
And I need to show only A and B markers, without showing others between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Api - drawing routes from an array of points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928906/google-maps-api-drawing-routes-from-an-array-of-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Polylines. Just draw polyline and set markers at A & B.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple